# How to extract data from 2 files and put it in different file (one line from one file and another line from other file and on..)?

Tags: python, file-handling

I have to files say one.txt and two.txt.

one.txt having following data  -

```
ab
cd
ef
```

two.txt having following data -

```
gh
ij
kl
```

**i want output like this in different file like

output.txt -

```
ab
gh
cd
ij
ef
kl
```

can anybody please help on this .

i have tried to open two files at time but somehow i am not able to do that..

Comment: According what you described, it should work. Show us your code to find the mistake. Remember: You learn best from mistakes you made.

Comment: Missing `use strict; use warnings;`. Always check the return value to see whether `open` was successful. Use 3-argument `open`, not 2-args.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to read lines from alternating files.

For example:

```
open my $fh1, '<', $file1 or die "$0: $file1: $!\n";
open my $fh2, '<', $file2 or die "$0: $file2: $!\n";

while () {
    defined(my $line1 = readline $fh1) or last;
    defined(my $line2 = readline $fh2) or last;
    print $line1, $line2;
}
```

Alternatively you can do the reading in the loop condition, but it might look a bit weird:

```
while (
    defined(my $line1 = readline $fh1) &&
    defined(my $line2 = readline $fh2)
) {
    print $line1, $line2;
}
```

This will stop as soon as the shortest file runs out of lines.

If you always want to process all lines, you can use the following solution (which generalizes to more than two files):

```
my @fhs = ($fh1, $fh2);
while (@fhs) {
    my $fh = shift @fhs;
    defined(my $line = readline $fh) or next;
    push @fhs, $fh;
    print $line;
}
```

This will keep reading lines from the first file handle in `@fhs` and then rotate the array (moving the first handle to the last position). When a file handle runs out of lines, it is dropped from the array. This continues until all handles are exhausted.

If you want it to stop as soon as the first handle runs out of lines, change `next` to `last`.